# Reading integers from a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm facing the following problem in Haskell:

I want to parse such list:
`["1", "2", "3"]` into a `Maybe [Int]`. What I can do is, using `readMaybe` from `Text.Read`, is get a `[Maybe Int]` int the following way:

```
parseList :: [String] -> [Maybe Int]
parseList l = map readMaybe l :: [Maybe Int]
```

I could then do:

```
parseListMaybe :: [String] -> Maybe [Int]
parseListMaybe l = if (any isNothing parsed) then Nothing
                   else (Just $ catMaybes parsed)
                   where parsed = parseList l
```

But this doesn't seem to me like the most elegant and precise way to solve this. I would appreciate some hints on this

Comment: `parseListMaybe = sequence . map readMaybe`.

Comment: or even shorter - `traverse readMaybe` or `mapM readMaybe` if you prefer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`sequence`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sequence) from `Control.Monad`:

```
\> import Control.Monad (sequence)
\> import Text.Read (readMaybe)
\> sequence (readMaybe <$> ["1", "2", "3"]) :: Maybe [Int]
Just [1,2,3]
\> sequence (readMaybe <$> ["1", "xyz", "3"]) :: Maybe [Int]
Nothing
```